# Find the derivative of the function $F(t) = \int_{t}^{2} \sqrt{tx} \sin{\left(tx \right)}\, dx$

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I try to find the derivative of following function:

$$F(t) = \int_{t}^{2} \sqrt{tx} \sin{\left(tx \right)}\, dx$$

But in the end I get an expression that contains the Fresnel integral. Is it possible to get a simpler solution?
I use the following formula:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For $ t> 0 $,

Put $ \;  xt=u\;  $ to get

$$F(t)=\frac 1t\int_{t^2}^{2t}\sqrt{u}\sin(u)du$$

Thus, by FTC and chain rule,
$$F'(t)=\frac{- 1}{t}F(t)+$$
$$\frac 1t\Bigl(2\sqrt{2t}\sin(2t)-2t\sqrt{t^2}\sin(t^2)\Bigr)$$